# Genetic Algorithm and Substitution Cipher

Tags: algorithm, encryption, genetic-algorithm

I want to write a genetic algorithm that decodes a string encoded with a substitution cipher. The input will be a string of lowercase characters from a to z and space characters, which do not get encoded. For example,

`uyd zjglk brsmh osc tjewn spdr uyd xqia fsv`

is a valid encoding of

`the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`

Notice that the space character does not get encoded.

Genes will be one-to-one, random character mappings.

To determine a gene's (or mapping's) fitness, the string to be decoded is applied this map, and the number of recognized English words in the result is counted.

The algorithm terminates when all the words in the input string are valid English words.

I do not want to use other techniques, such as frequency analysis.

Will this work? What can be said about performance?

Comment: well a brute force approach will work but as the name suggests it will not be an efficient one. Adding frequency analysis will prune a lot of extra fatty branches in real cases while in theory it can be proved that there are cases for which frequency analysis won't do anything better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counting the number of valid words gives a fitness landscape that is very "plateau-y".

In your example string, every individual will be assigned an integral fitness value between 0 and 9, inclusive, with the vast majority being at the low end of that range. This means if you generate an initial population, it's likely that all of them will have a fitness of zero. This means you can't have meaningful selection pressure, and the whole thing looks quite a lot like a random walk. You'll occasionally stumble upon something that gets a word right, and at that point, the population will shift towards that individual.

Given enough time, (and assuming your words are short enough to have some hope of randomly finding one every once in a while), you will eventually find the string. Genetic algorithms with sensible (i.e., ergodic) operators will always find the optimal solution if you let them run far enough into the land of super-exponential time. However, it's very unlikely that a GA would be a very *good* way of solving the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A genetic algorithm often has "recombination" as well as "mutation" to create a new generation from the previous one.  You may want to consider this -- if you have two particular substitution ciphers in your generation and when you look at the parts of them that create english words, it may be possible to combine the non-conflicting parts of the two ciphers that create english words, and make a cipher that creates even more english words than either of the two original ciphers that you "mated."  If you don't do this, then the genetic algorithm may take longer.

Also, you may want to alter your choice of "fitness" function to something more complex than simply how many english words the cipher makes.  Intuitively, if there is an encrypted word that is fairly long (say 5 or more letters) and has some repeated letter(s), then if you succeed in translating this to an english word, it's probably typically much better evidence that this part of the cipher is correct, as opposed to if you have two or three different 2-letter words that translate to english.

As for the "will it work / what about performance", I agree with the general consensus that your genetic algorithm is basically a structured way to do random guessing, and initially it will probably often be hard to ensure your population of fit individuals have some individuals that are making good progress toward the correct solution, simply because there can be many ciphers that give incorrect english words, e.g. if you have a lot of 3-letter words with 3 distinct letters.  So you will either need a huge population size (at least in the beginning), or you'll have to restart the algorithm if you determine that your population is not getting any fitter (because they are all stuck near local optima that give a moderate number of english words, but they're totally off-track from the correct solution).

Answer (score 2):

For genetic algorithm you need a way to get next generation. Either you invent some way to cross two permutations into a third one or you just make random modifications of most successful permutations. The latter gives you essentially local search algorithm based on random walk, which is not too efficient in terms of time, but **may** converge.
The former won't do any good at all. For different permutations you may get non-zero word count even if they don't share a single correct letter pair. In short, substitution cypher is too nonlinear, so that your algorithm becomes a series of random guesses, something like bogosort. You may evaluate not a number of words, but something like "likelihood" of letter chains, but it will be pretty much a kind of frequency analysis.